# Does there exist a constant c such that for all n>c, n is representable?

Tags: algorithms

Given a positive integer $n$, we can always perform one of the two processes:

(i) Take the number $n$ and add it to the sum of digits of $n$

(ii) Take the number $n$ and add it to the product of digits of $n$

We call a positive integer m representable, if we can start with the number $1$ and by following the processes, get to the number $m$.

(For example $29$ is representable because $1>2>4>8>16>23>29$)

Does there exist a constant $c$, such that for all positive integers $n>c$, $n$ is always representable? In other words, are all numbers eventually after a certain point representable?

Some facts about this problem discovered so far:

$100$ is representable in $11$ ways

$108$ is not representable

$2024$ is representable in over a million ways.

Would be curious if this problem already exists anywhere or if anyone can offer any insight. Thanks.

Edit: Indeed, as the numbers become bigger and bigger, almost all of them will contain a zero at some point. This makes process (ii) useless. Alternatively, another question would be to change process (ii) into only multiplying the non zero digits, I wonder if the answer to the problem changes at all.

Comment: Empirically, the fraction of representable numbers $\le n$, for $n \ge 3$, seems to be maximized at $n = 9656$, with $8636/9656 \approx 0.894$ of those reachable. This ratio also seems to be $\le 0.89$ for $n \ge 46849$. Checked up to $n \le 10^7$.

Comment: Please don't use "Edit:".  Instead, revise the question so it reads well for someone who encounters it for the first time.  Please ask only one question per post.  If you want to ask about some alternate question (e.g., where you change process (ii)), please ask about that separately, with the 'Ask Question' button.